# AS3 error 2007: parameter child must be non null from book example

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements, removechild, stage

I am playing around with some puzzle bobble code from the book "Flash game development by example".

The prototype works, until the end of the lesson in which the code tries to make bubbles fall if there are no longer connected ones. Unfortunately, the writer of this book uses strange coding practices on occasion to prevent line breaks in his book.

Here is the problem area that throws the error:

```
with (bubCont) {
   removeChild(getChildByName(i+"_"+j));
}
```

Is there a way I can write this code so it won't use `with () {  }`?

I've tried simply removing the child with `bubCont.removeChild(...)`, but to no avail.

Comment: It's not problem of `with()`. It is not getting child object. i.e. `getChildByName(i+"_"+j)`.

Comment: Hmmm... Fair enough. I think it's time I throw this book out, lol.

Comment: Aha! I figured it out. It was a nasty typo that was in the book. Bad typo, bad!
The problem was getChildByName(i+"_"+j) needed to be getChildByName(i+","+j). You were right Rajneesh, ty for pointing that out! A comma, not an underscore XD